# Regex how pull out data from json

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I have a json array that I use in my application, and I need it elsewhere in that form so I have to keep it that way. I save it in a table inside my db ,and deserialize it when needed. But now I would like to do a query that filters some of that data.

Sample json

```
[{"name":"SampleName","surname":"SampleSurname"}]
```

i would like to be able to do a regex that gives me only strings within "".
like i want the name and it gives me "SampleName" without the quotes
How can i achieve that?

EDIT!

I already parse the JSON when i need to use it.I just implemented a filter on my list of data and wanted to filter the query directly from SQL without having to deserialize it.

So what i wanted to do was a query that does something similar to:
`select * from contacts where name like regexp'regexhere'` and get back only name that matches my search.I KNOW i can parse the json and have better results,i wanted to know a "faster" alternative

Comment: I suggest you use a JSON parser... However if you insist on regex, try this...
To get keys:
/"([^"]+)":/

To get values:
/:"([^"]+)"/

They aren't complex at all... Just pushing you in the right direction :)

Comment: I think i should explain more,I already use a parser inside my application for my data.I wanted to apply a filter on the data using directly a query using regex,without taking out data and deserializing it,as it is a simple search i don;t need it complex or anything else.

Comment: I think you might want to rethink your database schema.

Comment: @Shane you should add your answer btw,it helped me

Comment: sokie, that is good enough for me :)
Just observation and using the semicolon, nothing brilliant :P

Answer (score 1):

In java you can use Regular expression with pattern matching.

```
String result;
String str= "[{"+
      "name"+
      ":"
      +"SampleName"
      +","+
      "surname"+
      ":"+
      "SampleSurname"+
      "}]";
 String regex ="[a-zA-Z]+";//matches only characters from a-z or A-Z
 Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
 while (matcher.find( ))
 {
 result = matcher.group();     
 System.out.println(result);                 
 }
output
name
SampleName
surname
SampleSurname
```

Comment: This answers the first part of getting string between "".

Answer (score 0):

A JSON parser is included in Android, that will allow you to do just that really simply. You should have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have already implemented my parses that i use elsewhere,i would like to know how could i pull out same data using regex

Answer (score 0):

You should really parse the JSON. You can use a library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to achieve this if you do not wish to roll your own.

If you do, a regex like:

```
[^"]+[^"]+
```

will let you tokenize it, so you can roll your own.